# Using Pino as a logger for Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use `Pino` with `Sequelize`'s [`options.logging`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html):

> A function that gets executed every time Sequelize would log something. Function may receive multiple parameters but only first one is printed by console.log. To print all values use (...msg) => console.log(msg)

Here's what I've tried:

```
const pino = require('pino')
const logger = pino({ level: 'debug', prettyPrint: true })
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: '../db.sqlite3',
  logging: logger.debug()
})
```

But nothing is printed to the console. I know logging is working, as I `logger.debug('test')` works when called elsewhere in the code.

I found [this](https://github.com/jsumners/abstract-logging) library (from [this](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/issues/105) issue) but I am not really sure how to use it with Sequelize.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to call your function, you just need to pass it to Sequelize.

So basically you should write `logging: msg => logger.info(msg)`, for example. Don't worry about losing some other parameters, `console.log` only uses the first one (as described in the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html)).

Simple working example:

```js
{
  // ...

  logging: sql => logger.info(sql),

  // ...
}
```

Full (or almost full) clone of `console.log` behavior:

```js
{
  // ...

  logging: (sql, timing) => logger.info(sql, typeof timing === 'number' ? `Elapsed time: ${timing}ms` : ''),

  // ...
}
```

Tip: You can use the `logging` option for each of your queries and they will obviously work the same way.

Tip #2: You can also use `logging: logger.info.bind(logger)`. But you will probably search for another workaround if you choose this one :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. But in your second example, `timing` is a JSON object containing query details, not a number.